# Получение метода Retrofit2 по его адресу (endpoint)

Tags: android, retrofit2

Можно ли как-либо получить метод по его адресу (endpoint)?
Например, если у меня есть интерфейс:

```
public interface TestApi {
    @POST("first")
    Call<MessageRs> getFirstCommand(@Body MessageRq rq);

    @POST("second")
    Call<MessageRs> getSecondCommand(@Body MessageRq rq);
}
```

и в коде приложения я динамически получаю адрес, на который нужно послать следующий запрос, например:

```
nextRqUrl = "second";  // или может быть "first"
```

можно ли каким-либо образом выполнить один из методов `getFirstCommand` или `getSecondCommand` в зависимости от этого адреса?

Comment: `switch(next){case "second":...` не?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Retrofit есть полезная аннотация `Url`, позволяющая делать запрос по динамически формируемому адресу. Допустим у вас такой код:

```
public interface TestApi {
    @POST
    Call<MessageRs> getCommand(@Url String url, @Body MessageRq rq);
}

...

Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl("https://your.api.url/somepath/");
    .build();
TestApiService service = retrofit.create(TestApi.class);
MessageRq msg = new MessageRq();
```

Есть 3 разных варианта того, куда уйдет запрос:

```
// post to https://example.com/test/path
service.getCommand("https://example.com/test/path", msg);

// post to https://your.api.url/somepath/test/path
service.getCommand("test/path", msg);

// post to https://your.api.url/test/path
service.getCommand("/test/path", msg);
```

В вашем случае подходит вариант №2